# Type-hinting a variable to have the same type as another variable in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

Example:

```py
def f(...): ...
v: type(f) = decorate(f)
```

But VSCode's Python Language Server doesn't seem to recognize it (and MyPy gives it `object` type?).

Part of the problem here is that `decorate` is not manually typed and is improperly inferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type expressions are evaluated statically by the type checker.* Complicated expressions such as `type(f)` are not guaranteed to work, because `type(f)` evaluates to the *runtime* type of `f`, not its statically annotated value.** The type checker does not know what that runtime type will be. In general, you should stick to the type expressions described in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for maximum compatibility.

> Part of the problem here is that `decorate` is not manually typed and is improperly inferred.

So fix it. For example, you could say that it returns an object of the same type as its argument:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')
d = typing.cast(typing.Callable[[T], T], decorate)
v = d(f) # v is inferred to have the same type as f
```

---

* Type expressions are also evaluated at runtime, stored in the `__annotations__` field, and then never used again unless some code decides to introspect them. This runtime functionality is rarely used and not relevant to the question.
** In fact it's worse than that, because someone might have monkey-patched your module with a custom `type()` that does something completely different from the builtin.